# Python Spyder Variable Explorer - Print as table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ide

I have a program which generates a lot of variables which are then shown in the variable explorer organized as such:

```
Name | Type | Size | Value

data1  float  1      45

data2  float  1      37
```

etc.

I want to print this Variable Explorer table to a `txt` or `csv` file without having to create a DataFrame by specifying each variable individually. Can this be done?

Comment: Perhaps you're IDE provides such a functionality, you'll probably need to specify what you are using. You should really *organize your data instead of just dumping it all into individual variables in the global scope*. That being said, you should be able to sift through `globals()` and do what you need.

Comment: I added Spyder into the subject line.